# How to fetch the bucket region and pass it to client o generate the presigned URLS aws s3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this code to generate the presigned URL for a recent object matching a string.

The issue is that how can I pass the correct region to the s3 client while generating the URL, this code is of no use if it is not generating the correct url

````
#! /usr/bin/python
#This script generates S3 object pre-signed URL

import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def keys(bucket_name, prefix="", delimiter="/"):
    """Generate a key listings
    :param bucket_name: string
    :param prefix: string
    :param delimiter: string
    """
    for page in (
        boto3.client("s3")
        .get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
        .paginate(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Prefix=prefix[len(delimiter) :] if prefix.startswith(delimiter) else prefix,
            **{"StartAfter": prefix} if prefix.endswith(delimiter) else {}
        )
    ):
        for content in page.get("Contents", ()):
            yield content["Key"]

def latest(bucket_name, prefix):
    """Generate a latest logfile
    :param bucket_name: string
    :param prefix: string
    :return: Object keys
    """
    return(max(i for i in keys(bucket_name) if prefix in i))

def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response

print(create_presigned_url("database-backup", latest("database-backup", "my-backup")))```
````

Comment: Can you please explain your end-goal a little clearer? Are you simply wanting to get a pre-signed URL for the latest backup file, which is defined as the most recent object created in the given bucket? Did you write this code?

Comment: I have done it. bucket might have multiple folders and each folder can have multiple database backups of multple databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing @john's answer.

```
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object
    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.session.Session(
        region_name=boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)["LocationConstraint"]
    ).client("s3")
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding upon @wpp's answer, your code would look something like this:

```py
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):

    # Get region for bucket
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=response['LocationConstraint'])
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
```

Comment: here the s3_client is being repeated, can we get rid of that?

Comment: The first one is used to obtain the bucket location. The second is used to request the pre-signed URL. You could put the first one in a global variable rather than recreating it each time. Do you have a particular issue with creating it twice?

Comment: You are also specifying a particular region in the second instance of `s3_client`, which may not match the first instance (rightly so). This construction of 2 instance of the client is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To get bucket's region, use `get_bucket_location()` method of S3 client.

It might be required of you to create boto3 session in this region, and then client from that session.

Comment: I was referring to a link and got this, ```def get_location(client, bucket_name):
    response = client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)
    return response['LocationConstraint']``` how this will fit in my code, can you help

Comment: You need to get location before you create client, and then create boto3 session by doing `session = boto3.Session(region_name=location)`, and then client `s3_client = session.client('s3')`. But to be honest I don't remember whether making client regional will affect URL generation, so you need to test that.

Comment: How is this  location `boto3.Session(region_name=location)` coming ?

Comment: will this work ```    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=get_bucket_location(bucket_name))```

Comment: Gives me error,     ```session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=get_bucket_location(bucket_name))
NameError: name 'get_bucket_location' is not defined```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to adapt some piece of code without really understanding how it works. I'm afraid I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

**From the [`boto3`](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) use this class** *(Refer to the example at the bottom)*

[image: s3.client class]

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
```

**These are the available methods:**

`get_bucket_location(**kwargs)`

Returns the Region the bucket resides in. You set the bucket's Region using the `LocationConstraint` request parameter in a `CreateBucket` request. For more information, see [CreateBucket](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_bucket).

** Note that to use this implementation of the operation, you must be the bucket owner.

The following operations are related to `GetBucketLocation` (Refer to the [AWS API Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Type_API_Reference.html)):

`GetObject`
`CreateBucket`

Request Syntax

```
response = client.get_bucket_location(
    Bucket='string'
)
Parameters
Bucket (string) --
[REQUIRED]
```

The name of the bucket for which to get the location.

```
Return type
dict
Returns
Response Syntax
{
    'LocationConstraint': 'EU'|'eu-west-1'|'us-west-1'|'us-west-2'|'ap-south-1'|'ap-southeast-1'|'ap-southeast-2'|'ap-northeast-1'|'sa-east-1'|'cn-north-1'|'eu-central-1'
}
```

Response Structure

(dict) --
LocationConstraint (string) --
Specifies the Region where the bucket resides. For a list of all the Amazon S3 supported location constraints by Region, see Regions and Endpoints .

**Examples**

The following example returns bucket location.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.get_bucket_location(
    Bucket='examplebucket',
)

print(response)
Expected Output:

{
    'LocationConstraint': 'us-west-2',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```